# ant .apk build works, but debug from eclipse not. failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635)

Tags: java, android, playscape

Firstly - I am new to Android SDK. Only 3 days at it.

When I build .apk using "ant clean debug" and then manually install it on device - app runs on device as it should;

But, if I use debug button at the top of eclipse - app is crashing on device with this kind of errors:

```
 10-13 15:54:39.968: E/dalvikvm(23793): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.playscape.publishingkit-2/libplayscape_pubkit.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libgnustl_shared.so" needed by "libplayscape_pubkit.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
```

I need to make debug button build to work, because this way the transfer to device and testing takes lot less time than building apk and installing it on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved with playscape SDK 1.16